# How to create pdf with latex?

Tags: errors, pdftex, python

Sorry about asking a stupid question. I'm just trying to use this, but don't know anything.

My problem is:
 I want to plot graph with python code.

I run it in terminal (I'm using mac) by calling:
`pdflatex -shell-escape plot_air_drag.tex`

> ! I can't find file `plot_air_drag.tex'.
>
> <*> plot_air_drag.tex
>
> (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
>
> Please type another input file name:

What is the way to run it?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{python}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
    from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from functools import partial

## set initial conditions and parameters
g = 9.81            # acceleration due to gravity
th = 45.            # set launch angle
th = th * np.pi/180.   # convert launch angle to radians
v0 = 20.0           # set speed

x0=0                # specify initial conditions
y0=0
vx0 = v0*sin(th)
vy0 = v0*cos(th)

## define function to compute f(X,t)
def f_func_k(k,state,time):
    f = zeros(4)    # create array to hold f vector
    f[0] = state[2] # f[0] = x component of velocity
    f[1] = state[3] # f[1] = x component of velocity
    f[2] = - k*(f[0]**2 + f[1]**2)**(0.5)*f[0]         # f[2] = acceleration in x direction
    f[3] = -g - k*(f[0]**2 + f[1]**2)**(0.5)*f[1]       # f[3] = acceleration in y direction
    return f

def gen_plot_data(s,k):
    f_func = partial(f_func_k,k)

    ## set initial state vector and time array
    X0 = [ x0, y0, vx0, vy0]        # set initial state of the system
    t0 = 0.
    # tf = input("Enter final time: ")
    # tau = input("Enter time step: ")
    tf = 3
    tau = 0.05

    # create time array starting at t0, ending at tf with a spacing tau
    t = arange(t0,tf,tau)

    ## solve ODE using odeint
    X = odeint(f_func,X0,t) # returns an 2-dimensional array with the
    # first index specifying the time and the
    # second index specifying the component of
    # the state vector

    # putting ':' as an index specifies all of the elements for
    # that index so x, y, vx, and vy are arrays at times specified
    # in the time array
    x = X[:,0]
    y = X[:,1]
    vx = X[:,2]
    vy = X[:,3]

    xy = zip(x,y)
    np.savetxt(s,xy,fmt='%0.5f')

gen_plot_data("plotdata1.dat",0.04)
gen_plot_data("plotdata2.dat",0)
\end{python}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[no marks,samples=100,axis lines=center,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,enlargelimits]
        \addplot table {plotdata1.dat};%
        \addplot[magenta] table {plotdata2.dat};%
    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you in the correct directory? You need to change to the path where the `.tex` file is located.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine on Mac with 10.9.2 and with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013). But:

**Save your file as** plot_air_drag.tex 
(the error message indicates you are using an different file name)

Modify your preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{python}
```

Start Terminal,

Type cd `Space` and drop the **folder** with the files there.

Hit Enter.

And use **pdflatex -shell-escape plot_air_drag.tex**
[image]